# Restricting Access to Edit in SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, sugarbean

I want to restrict editing of a record based on custom rules. I was able to restrict the list view, but cannot seem to get the edit restriction working.

In the custom controller, I have

```
class CustomOpportunitiesController extends SugarController { 

protected function action_editview() {
    $this->bean = new CustomOpportunity();
    // parent::action_editview(); // There is no action_editview() in SugarController
    $this->view_object_map['bean'] = $this->bean;
    $this->view = 'edit';
}
```

However when I add this, any time I try to edit a record it goes to Create Record instead!

There is absolutely no (useful) documentation on this either.
http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/ACL

Version 6.5.13.

(I also have code in the subclass but it's commented out right now.)

```
class CustomOpportunity extends Opportunity {
    // function ACLAccess($view,$is_owner='not_set') {  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. If we're using a custom controller like in your code, you could try this:

```
public function action_editview()
{
    /* Set view */
    if (/*your condition here*/)
    {
        $this->view = 'noaccess';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->view = 'edit';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Ps. The reason your code would appear to create a new record seems to be due to the "$this->bean = new CustomOpportunity();" -line, where you overwrite the bean you are about to edit with a new, fresh record :-)

Comment: Oh really? I put the condition in the controller instead of the bean? I had the the condition in my custom bean, but it was not using it, so that is why I thought it needed to instantiate my custom bean. I copied action_listview() where I restrict access to listing, so I thought it would work the same way.